# Why perl script gets '429 Too many requests' from YouTube server while web browser loads webpages fine

Tags: perl, youtube, rate-limiting

YouTube returns [429 Too many requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429) to perl script while any web browser on same computer downloads YouTube webpages properly.

A search for YouTube 'rate limiting' timeout was unsuccessful.

There are lot of references to [youtube-dl](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues/22839) issues of similar nature.

At this moment I am puzzled why web browser is working fine but perl script gets '429 Too many requests' for retrieving even single webpage.

I did mass 'verification' of *bookmarked* videos stored in DB file more than 24 hours ago. As of this moment `429 Too many requests` is still the answer perl scripts gets from YouTube server.

An attempt to spoof agent in perl script did not change the outcome

```
$ua->agent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.92 Safari/537.36');
```

Any clues are welcome to better understanding the problem.

Is a value of *rate limiting* timeout (as described `Retry-After: 3600`) on YouTube server against DDOS attack is described somewhere, nice to have a reference to this information.

Snippet code used *to capture* webpage with url of YouTube playlist

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use HTTP::Tiny;
use Getopt::Long qw(GetOptions);

use Data::Dumper;

my %opt;

$opt{url} = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XdTdu1MxDpE&list=UUgDFVgTnw_W5DftgN2NQApQ';

GetOptions(
        'url|u=s'   => \$opt{url},
        'debug|d'   => \$opt{debug},
        'help|?'    => \$opt{help},
        'man'       => \$opt{man}
) or pod2usage(2);

pod2usage(1) if $opt{help};
pod2usage(-exitval => 0, -verbose => 2) if $opt{man};

my $response = HTTP::Tiny->new->get($opt{url});

say Dumper($response) if $opt{debug};

if( $response->{success} ) {
    say $response->{content};
} else {
    say "Failed: $response->{status} $response->{reason}";
}

__END__

=head1 NAME

.......
```

Output

```
Failed: 429 Too Many Requests
```

Answer (score 2):

No one knows how YouTube handles this, but entire networks may be blocked, so the actions of others affect what you are able to do. If you are on shared hosting or a VPS, a proxy in another IP block might help. Read those reports about youtube-dl to see the advice—there's plenty of it.

As a very popular service, they are probably constantly changing the secret rules to keep up with various attacks. Superstition also includes:

- Handle cookies, maybe adding the cookie for a solved captcha from an interactive browser
- Don't use IPv6
- Make fewer than one requests per second
- Don't use a suspicious User-agent string
- Use the [YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3)